# Семь пятниц на неделе - в буквальном смысле

Tags: смысл, идиомы

В обзоре кинопрьемьер осени, критик пишет: *Для нас первый уик-энд — это стартовая неделя. Будь там два выходных или все **семь пятниц на неделе**...* Выражение ***семь пятниц на неделе*** употреблено здесь не как идиома, а в буквальном (если так можно выразиться) смысле. **С какой целью это сделано?** **Какого эффекта достигает автор обзора неидиоматическим использованием идиомы?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это один из наиболее ярких стилистических приемов обновления фразеологизмов —  разрушение их образного значения. В подобных ситуациях возникают каламбуры, построенные на так называемой внешней омонимии фразеологизмов и свободных сочетаний слов.

Фразеологическое выражение "Семь пятниц на неделе" пришло к нам из старинной торговой практики на Руси.. Когда-то пятница была свободным от работы и базарным днём, поэтому она долгое время была также и днём исполнения различных торговых обязательств. В пятницу, получая деньги, давали честное слово привезти на следующий базарный день заказанный товар. В пятницу, получая товар, обещали на следующей неделе отдать за него деньги. Таким образом, исполнить договор следовало в течение недели. Если один участник не выполнял свое обязательство, про него говорили, что у него «семь пятниц на неделе», то есть время на обещания у него есть, а времени на исполнение обещаний — нет.

*Для нас первый уик-энд — это стартовая неделя. Будь там два выходных или все семь пятниц на неделе...* Это каламбур, имеющий двойной смысл: первый уик-энд важен и значим как старт, несмотря на возможное обилие выходных (все пятницы — выходные) и несмотря на возможные отговорки.
Видимо, речь идёт о старте кинопроката; новый фильм начинается с выходного дня, а он во всех странах разный: где — в пятницу, где — в субботу, где — в воскресенье.

Comment: Очень интересно. Спасибо, Людмила!